# Apache Cordova Installation fails on Yosemite

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm-install

I'm trying to install the cordova CLI using the command line from the Apache website. 
I don't understand what happened but I can't.

I tried the following command line, which failed almost directly (it creates a cordova directory inside ~/.npm folder) :

```
$ npm install -g cordova
npm ERR! Darwin 14.3.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "cordova"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13

npm ERR! Error: EACCES, rmdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, rmdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova']
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: EACCES, rmdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova'
npm ERR! error rolling back     at Error (native)
npm ERR! error rolling back  { [Error: EACCES, rmdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: -13,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova' }
```

Then I tried to run it with sudo. It seems to extract several directory in ~/.npm but it still running in the console without logging anything in the debug file (neither in the console). 
After a few minutes, I got a really really weird behavior. It seems that I lost my internet connection because I can't access anything on my browsers until I kill the installation in the console (I tried 4 times to be sure it's not a coincidence, and it's definitely not cuz at the moment I type ctrl+c, my web pages are loading). But even more weird, my browsers can't load any pages, but I can't ping www.google.com from a console window.

I don't know what to do :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem while installing cordova. Here's what I did -

`sudo npm cache clean`

and then,

`sudo npm install -g cordova`

I also have a newer `npm` version. So if it doesn't work then try upgrading your `npm` to `v2.12.1(my version)` or higher.

If you still find any error (i.e. ENOENT) I would say uninstall and reinstall `node` from [nodejs.org](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) or using `brew`(the best way).

Comment: Ok I upgraded nom and it solved a part of my problem. However, I'm still unable to install Cordova. It fails on a dependency installation : /usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/abbrev-ef9cc920 (ENOENT -2). Any ideas ?

Comment: @JulianLeCalvez Install latest version of npm, execute 'npm cache clean' and try again

Comment: @JulianLeCalvez did you installed a new `npm` or upgrade the older one?

Comment: ENOENT (I guess it's about of wrong path) happens while installing packages globally without sudo, or canceling some installation process with `ctrc+c`. I would say uninstall and reinstall `node` from [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) or using `brew`(the best way).

Comment: I reinstalled node from the website's installer and now it works ! Thank you ! Update your answer and i'll accept it !

Comment: I guess you wanted me to add the node reinstallation thing to my answer, which I did. Please let me know if there anything else you wanted me to do.